# How to use input words as integers

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

So I am trying to set up a way that someone could enter in how they want a sign with the following rules.

The charge for all signs is a minimum of $35.00.

The first five letters or numbers are included in the minimum charge; there is a $4 charge for each additional character.

If the sign is make of oak, add $20.00. No charge is added for pine.

Black or white characters are included in the minimum charge; there is an additional $15 charge for gold-leaf lettering.

So if someone were to get 8 characters with an oak sign and gold lettering the total should be $82 however my code seems to only process the first if statement I put up making it only $47 and the only way I can fix this is if I change the color words into using numbers rather than the actual words. I was wondering if there was a way to still use the words instead of replacing them with numbers

## Code that fails with the words:

```
# Declare and initialize variables here.

Charge = 35.00 
Black = 0.00
White = 0.00
Gold = 15.00
Pine = 0.00
Oak = 20.00
Characters = 0.00
Color = 0.00
Wood = 0.00

numChars = int(input("How many characters would you like on your sign? :"))

color = input("What color would you like your words on your sign to be? Black, White, or Gold :")

woodType = input("What type of wood would you like your sign to be? Pine or Oak :")


# Write assignment and if statements here as appropriate.
if numChars > 5:
    Characters = (numChars - 5) * 4.00 
    if color == Gold:
        Color = 15.00
        if woodType == Oak:
            Wood = 20.00

print("The charge for this sign is $" + str(Charge + Characters + Color + Wood))
```

## Code that works using numbers instead of words:

```
    # Declare and initialize variables here.

Charge = 35.00 
Black = 0.00
White = 0.00
Gold = 15.00
Pine = 0.00
Oak = 20.00
Characters = 0.00
Color = 0.00
Wood = 0.00

numChars = int(input("How many characters would you like on your sign? :"))

color = int(input("What color would you like your words on your sign to be? Black(1), White(2), or Gold(3) :"))

woodType = int(input("What type of wood would you like your sign to be? Pine(1) or Oak(2) :"))


# Write assignment and if statements here as appropriate.
if numChars > 5:
    Characters = (numChars - 5) * 4.00 
    if color == 3:
        Color = 15.00
        if woodType == 2:
            Wood = 20.00

print("The charge for this sign is $" + str(Charge + Characters + Color + Wood))
```

Comment: `if Color == "Gold":`

Comment: You need to put quotes around a string, otherwise it's a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, replace `Gold` with `"Gold"` and `Oak` with `"Oak"`.

You see, the problem is that you are checking if `color` and `woodType` are equal to `Gold` and `Oak` **variables**, but you want to check if they're equal to these **strings**, so you need to put them inside of *quotation marks*.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but my interpreter says the output is wrong when the output is exactly the same as the expected output for some reason. but, thank you for helping me figure that part out!\

Comment: @JohnnyRockstar What do you mean *the interpreter says the output is wrong*?!

Comment: It is part of some of my work in Python with understanding if statements although it is checked by a program. It states the result output is "The charge for this sign is $82" but the Expected output is "The charge for this sign is $82" and the only thing it says is that there is an error on line 13 saying it is an invalid literal for int() with base 10. I only get that error if I use a word instead of a number for the input of numChars but if I swap it for a word like the others then the math on line 22 will be invalid. I already talked to my professor and she is going to look into it.

Comment: Turns out the software that the assignment was meant to be programmed in didn't want the ability to actually type out the sign numbers and color and woodtype as an input and to simply state that it was 8, gold, and oak instead of being able to work as it's own code. Therefore the answer was accepted as correct once numChars was set to 8, Color = Gold, woodType = Oak and I didn't get the error. Was making the code too complex for it to want to accept.

Comment: @JohnnyRockstar Hi, did my answer solved your problem? if so, feel free to accept it.